# Disable a decoder type in ZBar's C++ API

Tags: c++, zbar

I have a barcode which is incorrectly recognized as EAN, when it is in fact Code 39. I know the type of barcode beforehand, so I want to tell ZBar to look only for Code 39 barcodes.

I found a related question - [Wrong decoding of barcodes also in ZBAR SDK example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214255/wrong-decoding-of-barcodes-also-in-zbar-sdk-example), but the function it mentions is `setSymbology()`, and it is absent from the C++ API. Maybe it's only in the iPhone SDK?

Is there an equivalent function for the C++ API?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's an exact equivalent to `setSymbology()` but I used `ImageScanner::set_config()` to do the job.

```
scanner.set_config(ZBAR_EAN8, ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE, 0);
scanner.set_config(ZBAR_EAN13, ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE, 0);
```

Using this code I could disable all the EAN decoders.